# visibility hidden on react native not working, to take space even not shown?

Tags: react-native

I have TouchableOpacity in a space between flex container that I want to take space even not shown,

My code:

```
<TouchableOpacity
  style={showClear && { visibility: 'hidden' }}
  onPress={() => this.props.clearCompleted()}>
  <Text>Clear Completed</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

display: none works but it doesn't take space, the code above dont work but does in web?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In my case, I needed to use the element, so I did something like this:

```
<TextInput style={{opacity: 0, height: 0}} {...props} />
```

I hope this works for someone else with my problem.

Comment: only, opacity : 0 will allow action views to take user action.

Comment: You can also set `pointerEvents="none"` in your view when opacity is 0.

Answer (score 23):

**Update**

---

React Native's StyleSheet now supports toggling visibility using `display: 'none'` and `display:flex`.

---

Not all CSS are supported in React Native, that include `visibility: hidden` or `display:none`.

To hide a component, not to render it at all, render empty View or null. Or you want to switch a component visibility, verify react's state

```js
<View>
   { !showClear && (
      <TouchableOpacity
         onPress={() => this.props.clearCompleted()}>
         <Text>Clear Completed</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
   }
</View>
```

`showClear` is kept in state

Answer (score 5):

As Leu mentioned, you can just render `null`.

Another option if you want to keep the area used by TouchableOpacity is setting up `opacity: 0.0` in style, but then you have to remember to set also `disabled={false}` in props of the TouchableOpacity, to avoid call clicking action on invisible area

Answer (score 4):

Just setting the opacity to 0 was enough for my use case.

Answer (score 2):

If we want to make sure element takes space on DOM but is kept hidden to user,

**Step 1:** Hide it from user using `opacity: 0` .

**Step 2:** Disable interactions of hidden element.

Our JSX should be like below:

```
<IconButton
  icon="close"
  disabled
  style={styles.hiddenElement}
  onPress={() => console.log("Pressed")}
/>
```

Our stylesheet should look like below:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  ...
  hiddenElement: {
    opacity: 0,
  },
  ...
});
```

Comment: `pointerEvents: 'none'` is also helpful for your #2.  Like if you have a View that contains various Buttons or inputs or whatnot.